# Cannot boot but hdd is detected

Tags: hard-drive, boot

My HDD is spinning and detected by BIOS but it is saying "No boot device found" What's wrong with it? Is it bricked? Is data recovery possible? I have tried resetting the BIOS settings to default but no luck there.

EDIT: The first boot device is the hdd

EDIT2: An hour or so before I discovered this, the computer sounded like a very loud vacuum. I don't know if this was the hard drive head scratching against the platters or if it was just the fan

Comment: Sounds like the OS is faulty. You can try to re-install it. But you may want to slave it on another machine first to back up anything which isn't backed up!

Comment: or if you do not want to take out the drive, get yourself a Linux Live USB, boot from it and check if you can access the data, if not a test on another PC should be done just to make sure it is not the MB (less likely - but you never know) - and as @Dave said - backup as soon as you can read the data!!!

Comment: I have been able to slave the drive onto another computer and run a chkdisk on it. It only found errors that are completely extraneous and did not fix it

Comment: No, slave it to ensure you have a back up; Now, re-install the OS#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that the computer had a virus and destroyed most of the data therefore not worth backing up. I reinstalled the OS and it did work.